# Meaning of notation $ G(x, t; \bar x, 0) $

Tags: functions, notation

What is the meaning of the notation in $ G(x, t~;~ \bar x, 0) $? By this, I mean the semicolon and subsequent terms.

The context is that $ G(x, t; \bar x, 0) $ is defined as $ G(x, t; \bar x, 0) $ = $ \frac{1}{\sqrt{4 \pi k t}} ~e^{\frac{-(x - \bar x)^2}{4kt}}$.

Comment: Why denote it as $ G(x, t; \bar x, 0) $ instead of, lets say, $G(x, t, \bar x)$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distribution $ G(x, t; \bar x, 0)$ is the distribution of the random variable $x$ at time $t$ with $\bar x$ and $0$ being parameters.

If you write $ G(x, t, \bar x, 0)$ both $x$ and $ \bar x$ would be variables and $ G(x, t, \bar x, 0)$ will be the joint probability distribution. This only make sense if $\bar x$ is also a variable.

In this case the semicolon is separating the variables and the parameters.

Comment: Why do you talk about "distribution of the random variable $x$"? What makes you think this is about probability?

Comment: @md2perpe As you state in your answer, G is the distribution of a random variable $x$ following the 1D diffusion equation. So in this case, given $x_0=x(t=0)$, x is a random variable and has the probability distribution $G(x,t;x_0,0)$. But probably there are lot's of interpretations that we can give to this function.

Answer (score 3):

$G$ is the [Green's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function#Table_of_Green.27s_functions) for the 1D diffusion equation. It describes how the value of a field $\psi$ at one point and time depends on the value at another point and time:

$$\psi(x, t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} G(x, t; x_0, t_0) \, \psi(x_0, t_0) \, dx_0$$

The semicolon is just cosmetic to group arguments. The zero means that $t_0=0$. In this case we could also have taken $x_0=0$ since the expression for $G$ only depends on space through $x-x_0$, but the function will probably be used with $t_0=0$ and with varying $x_0$.